# HDDs occasionally "click" and dump this error

Tags: linux, hard-drive, raid, smart, mdadm

Every once in a while, my HDDs (6 1TB drives in a Linux md RAID-6 array) make a brief "click" sound, and I get this from `dmesg`. I don't really have any clue how to start diagnose this, or even how serious it is. I can provide any other information that might help.

```
[734275.661643] ata3.00: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x6 SErr 0x90202 action 0xe frozen
[734275.661647] ata3.00: irq_stat 0x00400000, PHY RDY changed
[734275.661650] ata3: SError: { RecovComm Persist PHYRdyChg 10B8B }
[734275.661652] ata3.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[734275.661656] ata3.00: cmd 60/00:08:00:08:3a/04:00:07:00:00/40 tag 1 ncq 524288 in
[734275.661656]          res 40/00:10:00:0c:3a/00:00:07:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[734275.661657] ata3.00: status: { DRDY }
[734275.661659] ata3.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[734275.661661] ata3.00: cmd 60/80:10:00:0c:3a/02:00:07:00:00/40 tag 2 ncq 327680 in
[734275.661661]          res 40/00:10:00:0c:3a/00:00:07:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[734275.661663] ata3.00: status: { DRDY }
[734275.661666] ata3: hard resetting link
[734279.860371] ata3: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[734279.882364] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/133
[734279.896422] ata3: EH complete
[735590.682564] ata1.00: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x4 SErr 0x90202 action 0xe frozen
[735590.682569] ata1.00: irq_stat 0x00400000, PHY RDY changed
[735590.682572] ata1: SError: { RecovComm Persist PHYRdyChg 10B8B }
[735590.682574] ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[735590.682578] ata1.00: cmd 60/00:10:00:7c:93/04:00:07:00:00/40 tag 2 ncq 524288 in
[735590.682578]          res 40/00:10:00:7c:93/00:00:07:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[735590.682579] ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
[735590.682582] ata1: hard resetting link
[735594.715103] ata1: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[735594.717729] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
[735594.731123] ata1: EH complete
[736745.389703] ata3.00: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x7 SErr 0x90202 action 0xe frozen
[736745.389707] ata3.00: irq_stat 0x00400000, PHY RDY changed
[736745.389710] ata3: SError: { RecovComm Persist PHYRdyChg 10B8B }
[736745.389712] ata3.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[736745.389715] ata3.00: cmd 60/00:00:00:44:e4/04:00:07:00:00/40 tag 0 ncq 524288 in
[736745.389715]          res 40/00:10:00:4c:e4/00:00:07:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[736745.389717] ata3.00: status: { DRDY }
[736745.389718] ata3.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[736745.389721] ata3.00: cmd 60/00:08:00:48:e4/04:00:07:00:00/40 tag 1 ncq 524288 in
[736745.389721]          res 40/00:10:00:4c:e4/00:00:07:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[736745.389723] ata3.00: status: { DRDY }
[736745.389724] ata3.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[736745.389726] ata3.00: cmd 60/80:10:00:4c:e4/02:00:07:00:00/40 tag 2 ncq 327680 in
[736745.389726]          res 40/00:10:00:4c:e4/00:00:07:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[736745.389728] ata3.00: status: { DRDY }
[736745.389731] ata3: hard resetting link
[736749.535411] ata3: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[736749.537993] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/133
[736749.551459] ata3: EH complete
[736871.093158] ata1.00: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x7 SErr 0x90202 action 0xe frozen
[736871.093164] ata1.00: irq_stat 0x00400000, PHY RDY changed
[736871.093167] ata1: SError: { RecovComm Persist PHYRdyChg 10B8B }
[736871.093170] ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[736871.093175] ata1.00: cmd 60/00:00:00:14:ec/04:00:07:00:00/40 tag 0 ncq 524288 in
[736871.093175]          res 40/00:10:00:1c:ec/00:00:07:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[736871.093178] ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
[736871.093180] ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[736871.093184] ata1.00: cmd 60/00:08:00:18:ec/04:00:07:00:00/40 tag 1 ncq 524288 in
[736871.093184]          res 40/00:10:00:1c:ec/00:00:07:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[736871.093186] ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
[736871.093188] ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[736871.093192] ata1.00: cmd 60/80:10:00:1c:ec/02:00:07:00:00/40 tag 2 ncq 327680 in
[736871.093192]          res 40/00:10:00:1c:ec/00:00:07:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[736871.093194] ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
[736871.093198] ata1: hard resetting link
[736871.093226] ata3.00: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x4 SErr 0x90202 action 0xe frozen
[736871.093238] ata3.00: irq_stat 0x00400000, PHY RDY changed
[736871.093247] ata3: SError: { RecovComm Persist PHYRdyChg 10B8B }
[736871.093254] ata3.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[736871.093268] ata3.00: cmd 60/00:10:00:18:ec/04:00:07:00:00/40 tag 2 ncq 524288 in
[736871.093268]          res 40/00:10:00:18:ec/00:00:07:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[736871.093275] ata3.00: status: { DRDY }
[736871.093285] ata3: hard resetting link
[736875.185513] ata1: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[736875.188123] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
[736875.201464] ata1: EH complete
[736875.361508] ata3: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[736875.364080] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/133
[736875.377505] ata3: EH complete
```

Here's what `mdadm` says:

```
root@cobalt:~# mdadm --detail /dev/md2
/dev/md2:
        Version : 1.2
  Creation Time : Wed Oct  3 23:25:43 2012
     Raid Level : raid6
     Array Size : 3711338496 (3539.41 GiB 3800.41 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 927834624 (884.85 GiB 950.10 GB)
   Raid Devices : 6
  Total Devices : 6
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Sat Oct  4 16:19:32 2014
          State : clean 
 Active Devices : 6
Working Devices : 6
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

           Name : cobalt:2  (local to host cobalt)
           UUID : 4e8d6d0f:76148df5:f9356fe4:4aff770c
         Events : 664

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8        3        0      active sync   /dev/sda3
       1       8       19        1      active sync   /dev/sdb3
       2       8       35        2      active sync   /dev/sdc3
       3       8       51        3      active sync   /dev/sdd3
       4       8       67        4      active sync   /dev/sde3
       5       8       83        5      active sync   /dev/sdf3
```

Here's SMART data from /dev/sda:

```
root@cobalt:~# smartctl -x /dev/sda
smartctl 6.2 2013-07-26 r3841 [x86_64-linux-3.13.0-27-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-13, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Seagate Barracuda 7200.12
Device Model:     ST31000524AS
Serial Number:    5VPBKAB7
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000c50 0493faba7
Firmware Version: JC4B
User Capacity:    1,000,204,886,016 bytes [1.00 TB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    7200 rpm
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 4
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.0, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Sat Oct  4 16:22:26 2014 EDT
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled
AAM level is:     208 (intermediate), recommended: 208
APM feature is:   Unavailable
Rd look-ahead is: Enabled
Write cache is:   Enabled
ATA Security is:  Disabled, NOT FROZEN [SEC1]
Wt Cache Reorder: Unknown

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x82) Offline data collection activity
                    was completed without error.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Enabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (  609) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x7b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   1) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 179) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x103f) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 10
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAGS    VALUE WORST THRESH FAIL RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     POSR--   119   099   006    -    226103712
  3 Spin_Up_Time            PO----   100   100   000    -    0
  4 Start_Stop_Count        -O--CK   100   100   020    -    117
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   PO--CK   100   100   036    -    0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         POSR--   083   060   030    -    226371995
  9 Power_On_Hours          -O--CK   081   081   000    -    17014
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        PO--C-   100   100   097    -    0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       -O--CK   100   100   020    -    117
183 Runtime_Bad_Block       -O--CK   071   071   000    -    29
184 End-to-End_Error        -O--CK   100   100   099    -    0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      -O--CK   097   097   000    -    3
188 Command_Timeout         -O--CK   100   099   000    -    4
189 High_Fly_Writes         -O-RCK   100   100   000    -    0
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel -O---K   061   053   045    -    39 (Min/Max 38/39)
194 Temperature_Celsius     -O---K   039   047   000    -    39 (0 17 0 0 0)
195 Hardware_ECC_Recovered  -O-RC-   035   025   000    -    226103712
197 Current_Pending_Sector  -O--C-   100   100   000    -    0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   ----C-   100   100   000    -    0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    -OSRCK   200   200   000    -    4
240 Head_Flying_Hours       ------   100   253   000    -    99664716120872
241 Total_LBAs_Written      ------   100   253   000    -    1687451554
242 Total_LBAs_Read         ------   100   253   000    -    1287307392
                            ||||||_ K auto-keep
                            |||||__ C event count
                            ||||___ R error rate
                            |||____ S speed/performance
                            ||_____ O updated online
                            |______ P prefailure warning

General Purpose Log Directory Version 1
SMART           Log Directory Version 1 [multi-sector log support]
Address    Access  R/W   Size  Description
0x00       GPL,SL  R/O      1  Log Directory
0x01       GPL,SL  R/O      1  Summary SMART error log
0x02       GPL,SL  R/O      5  Comprehensive SMART error log
0x03       GPL     R/O      5  Ext. Comprehensive SMART error log
0x06       GPL,SL  R/O      1  SMART self-test log
0x07       GPL     R/O      1  Extended self-test log
0x09       GPL,SL  R/W      1  Selective self-test log
0x10       GPL     R/O      1  NCQ Command Error log
0x11       GPL     R/O      1  SATA Phy Event Counters
0x21       GPL     R/O      1  Write stream error log
0x22       GPL     R/O      1  Read stream error log
0x80-0x9f  GPL,SL  R/W     16  Host vendor specific log
0xa1       GPL,SL  VS      20  Device vendor specific log
0xa2       GPL     VS    2248  Device vendor specific log
0xa8       GPL,SL  VS     129  Device vendor specific log
0xa9       GPL,SL  VS       1  Device vendor specific log
0xb0       GPL     VS    2928  Device vendor specific log
0xbd       GPL     VS     252  Device vendor specific log
0xbe-0xbf  GPL     VS   65535  Device vendor specific log
0xc0       GPL,SL  VS       1  Device vendor specific log
0xe0       GPL,SL  R/W      1  SCT Command/Status
0xe1       GPL,SL  R/W      1  SCT Data Transfer

SMART Extended Comprehensive Error Log Version: 1 (5 sectors)
Device Error Count: 3
    CR     = Command Register
    FEATR  = Features Register
    COUNT  = Count (was: Sector Count) Register
    LBA_48 = Upper bytes of LBA High/Mid/Low Registers ]  ATA-8
    LH     = LBA High (was: Cylinder High) Register    ]   LBA
    LM     = LBA Mid (was: Cylinder Low) Register      ] Register
    LL     = LBA Low (was: Sector Number) Register     ]
    DV     = Device (was: Device/Head) Register
    DC     = Device Control Register
    ER     = Error register
    ST     = Status register
Powered_Up_Time is measured from power on, and printed as
DDd+hh:mm:SS.sss where DD=days, hh=hours, mm=minutes,
SS=sec, and sss=millisec. It "wraps" after 49.710 days.

Error 3 [2] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 15745 hours (656 days + 1 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  40 -- 51 00 00 00 00 01 5a 53 b1 00 00  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x015a53b1 = 22696881

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  60 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 00 08 08 40 00     00:01:11.224  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 00 08 08 40 00     00:01:11.224  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 00 08 08 40 00     00:01:11.224  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 00 08 00 40 00     00:01:11.224  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 00 00 08 00 00 05 d2 1f f0 40 00     00:01:11.224  READ FPDMA QUEUED

Error 2 [1] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 15745 hours (656 days + 1 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  40 -- 51 00 00 00 00 01 5a 53 b1 00 00  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x015a53b1 = 22696881

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  60 00 00 00 08 00 00 08 be 2f 70 40 00     00:01:07.978  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 00 03 c0 40 00     00:01:07.978  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 00 01 00 00 00 01 5a 52 d8 40 00     00:01:07.978  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 00 00 08 00 00 03 04 75 40 40 00     00:01:07.978  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 00 00 20 00 00 00 24 72 00 40 00     00:01:07.977  READ FPDMA QUEUED

Error 1 [0] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 15745 hours (656 days + 1 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  40 -- 51 00 00 00 00 01 5a 53 b1 00 00  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x015a53b1 = 22696881

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  60 00 00 01 00 00 00 01 5a 52 d8 40 00     00:01:04.761  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 00 00 20 00 00 00 24 72 00 40 00     00:01:04.758  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 00 00 08 00 00 03 04 75 40 40 00     00:01:04.758  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  61 00 00 00 08 00 00 05 04 54 08 40 00     00:01:04.755  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 00 03 c0 40 00     00:01:04.752  READ FPDMA QUEUED

SMART Extended Self-test Log Version: 1 (1 sectors)
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     14257         -
# 2  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     14232         -
# 3  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%     14214         -
# 4  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     14208         -
# 5  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     14184         -
# 6  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     14160         -
# 7  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     14136         -
# 8  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     14112         -
# 9  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     14088         -
#10  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     14064         -
#11  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%     14046         -
#12  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     14040         -
#13  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     14016         -
#14  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     13992         -
#15  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     13968         -
#16  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     13944         -
#17  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     13920         -
#18  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     13896         -
#19  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%     13878         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.

SCT Status Version:                  3
SCT Version (vendor specific):       522 (0x020a)
SCT Support Level:                   1
Device State:                        Active (0)
Current Temperature:                    39 Celsius
Power Cycle Min/Max Temperature:     38/39 Celsius
Lifetime    Min/Max Temperature:     17/47 Celsius
Under/Over Temperature Limit Count:   0/0
SCT Temperature History Version:     2
Temperature Sampling Period:         1 minute
Temperature Logging Interval:        59 minutes
Min/Max recommended Temperature:     14/55 Celsius
Min/Max Temperature Limit:           10/60 Celsius
Temperature History Size (Index):    128 (117)

Index    Estimated Time   Temperature Celsius
 118    2014-09-29 11:09    36  *****************
 ...    ..(  4 skipped).    ..  *****************
 123    2014-09-29 16:04    36  *****************
 124    2014-09-29 17:03    37  ******************
 ...    ..(  4 skipped).    ..  ******************
   1    2014-09-29 21:58    37  ******************
   2    2014-09-29 22:57    36  *****************
 ...    ..(  6 skipped).    ..  *****************
   9    2014-09-30 05:50    36  *****************
  10    2014-09-30 06:49    37  ******************
  11    2014-09-30 07:48    36  *****************
 ...    ..( 21 skipped).    ..  *****************
  33    2014-10-01 05:26    36  *****************
  34    2014-10-01 06:25    37  ******************
 ...    ..( 10 skipped).    ..  ******************
  45    2014-10-01 17:14    37  ******************
  46    2014-10-01 18:13    38  *******************
 ...    ..(  2 skipped).    ..  *******************
  49    2014-10-01 21:10    38  *******************
  50    2014-10-01 22:09    37  ******************
 ...    ..( 32 skipped).    ..  ******************
  83    2014-10-03 06:36    37  ******************
  84    2014-10-03 07:35    38  *******************
 ...    ..(  9 skipped).    ..  *******************
  94    2014-10-03 17:25    38  *******************
  95    2014-10-03 18:24    39  ********************
  96    2014-10-03 19:23    39  ********************
  97    2014-10-03 20:22    38  *******************
  98    2014-10-03 21:21    37  ******************
 ...    ..(  6 skipped).    ..  ******************
 105    2014-10-04 04:14    37  ******************
 106    2014-10-04 05:13    38  *******************
 107    2014-10-04 06:12    37  ******************
 108    2014-10-04 07:11    37  ******************
 109    2014-10-04 08:10    37  ******************
 110    2014-10-04 09:09    38  *******************
 111    2014-10-04 10:08     ?  -
 112    2014-10-04 11:07    38  *******************
 113    2014-10-04 12:06     ?  -
 114    2014-10-04 13:05    38  *******************
 115    2014-10-04 14:04     ?  -
 116    2014-10-04 15:03    39  ********************
 117    2014-10-04 16:02    39  ********************

SCT Error Recovery Control:
           Read: Disabled
          Write: Disabled

Device Statistics (GP Log 0x04) not supported

SATA Phy Event Counters (GP Log 0x11)
ID      Size     Value  Description
0x000a  2            1  Device-to-host register FISes sent due to a COMRESET
0x0001  2            0  Command failed due to ICRC error
0x0003  2            0  R_ERR response for device-to-host data FIS
0x0004  2            0  R_ERR response for host-to-device data FIS
0x0006  2            0  R_ERR response for device-to-host non-data FIS
0x0007  2            0  R_ERR response for host-to-device non-data FIS
```

Comment: Looks like the drives are intermittently disconnecting from the system. Are the cables firmly seated? If not, this is probably some SATA controller issue.

Comment: I had a simliar problem a while ago. For me was the hard drive also clicking. It was the OS parking the head. Maybe [this](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Problem_with_hard_drive_clicking#Possible_solutions_.28Linux.29) is of help to you like it was for me.

Comment: I don't think it's a power-saving issue, because the drives are not idle. It's actually started being more frequent since I kicked off an off-site backup that's going to run continuously for the next day or so.

Answer (score 2):

The behavior you're experiencing appears to be the drives disconnecting from the system, reconnecting when the system hard resets the SATA link.

You might want to make sure your cables are undamaged, clean, and properly seated in the motherboard ports and drives. If this doesn't help, it may be a bug in the operating system or a problem with your SATA controller.

Comment: Could it be an overheating issue? Thermal shutdown on the HDDs themselves?

Comment: @Derecho no. Your `smartctl` data indicate the temperatures are well within normal operating limits (39 C is perfectly normal).